# Powershell List to formatted table

Tags: arrays, list, powershell

I am importing a CSV that has a format like this:

```
systemname, percentage, status, type
Server1,75,0,v
Server2,75,0,v
Server3,50,0,v
Server4,5,0,v
```

I have a need to output each systemname to the screen.  That alone is easy, but it puts it all in one column and takes up too much room if there are a lot of systems.  So I wanted to put all those systemnames in a table to make it look nice and neat when I output.  I came up with the following but there HAS to be an easier way.  This does work, btw.  Just... so many lines.

```
$lines = Import-Csv "c:\scripts\mysystems.csv"
$max = 0
foreach ($system in $lines)
{
    if ($system.systemname.Length -gt $max)
    {
        $max = $system.systemname.Length
    }
}
$cols = 5    
$temparray = @()
$temprow = @()
$tempname = ""
$i=0
$j=0
foreach ($system in $lines)
{
    $tempname = $system.systemname
    if ($system.systemname.Length -lt $max)
    {
        $x = $max - $system.systemname.Length
        while ($x -gt 0)
        {
            $tempname += " "
            $x--
        }
    }
    if ($i -le $cols-2)
    {
        $temprow += @($tempname)
        $i++
        $j++
        if ($j -eq $lines.Count)
        {
            $temparray += ,@($temprow)                  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $temprow += @($tempname)
        $temparray += ,@($temprow)
        $temprow = @()    
        $j++
        $i=0
    }            
}
write-output $temparray | % {$_ -join "`t`t"}
```

Thoughts on an easier solution?

Comment: Like this? `Import-Csv "c:\scripts\mysystems.csv" | Format-Wide -AutoSize`

Comment: `Import-Csv $filename | Format-Table` should be sufficient.

Comment: Well... :)  That would look much easier. BUT... I believe the correct answer would be:

`$lines = Import-Csv "c:\scripts\mysystems.csv"`
   
`$lines | format-wide -autosize`

Unless there's a way to do it with setting the variable at the same time as you all have shown?

Comment: @SaintFrag Like `Import-CSV "c:\scripts\mysystems.csv" | Tee-Object -Variable "lines" | Format-Wide -AutoSize` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shorten this using `Format-Wide` to:

```
Import-Csv "c:\scripts\mysystems.csv" |
Format-Wide -Column 5
```

Output:

```
Server1                 Server2                 Server3                 Server4                 Server11
Server12                Server13                Server14                Server21                Server22
Server23                Server24
```

The spacing will vary based on the console width. Personally I would like `Format-Wide` to support using both `-Column 5 -AutoSize` to minimize the space between the columns, but `-AutoSize` is only used to autodetect number of columns (depends on consolewidth) atm. I've added a suggestion on [UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/12355419-format-wide-allow-autosize-or-a-compact-para) to make it shrink the spacing like `Format-Table -AutoSize` does.